# How to use Aerospike aeroMapper.query method without the filter argument using java client

Tags: java, aerospike

I am trying to use Aerospike AeroMapper's query method through java client and the record selection logic is written in the policy so I have no need to pass any filter in the method.

```
policy.filterExp = getResultPolicy();
results = aeroMapper.query(policy, ResultDto.class, null);
```

I'm passing null for the 3rd argument which is the Filter expression and not getting the expected results. Am I missing something?

I also explored `AerospikeClient` methods which would match my requirement but no luck.

Answer (score 4):

Aerospike Java Object Mapper is a library that wraps the Aerospike Java Client which aims to lower the amount of code required when mapping POJOs (Plain Old Java Objects) to Aerospike and back as well as reducing some of the brittleness of the code.

`AeroMapper` is the main interface of the Java Object Mapper project and is not part of Aerospike Java Client.

The `query()` interface you used gets a `QueryPolicy` (that can contain a Filter Expression), a `class` (as you mentioned) and a `Filter` (Not a Filter Expression, a Filter is a secondary index based filter).

I suggest you read the GitHub README of Java Object Mapper - especially "Query" section:

https://github.com/aerospike/java-object-mapper#queries

And also checkout a query example from the GitHub repository tests that uses both Filter Expression and Filter (for applying 2 filters: 1 on a secondary index and 1 on the returned results):

https://github.com/aerospike/java-object-mapper/blob/main/src/test/java/com/aerospike/mapper/QueryTest.java#L150

Another tip: add your code, your expected results and the actual results that you get, this will make debugging much easier.